# Way to keep login state using JWT after logged in

Tags: reactjs, authentication, cookies, jwt, token

I'm wondeirng is there a original, and most used way to code "Way to keep logged in state".

Currently, I set log in button to 'MyPage' button after successful logged in.

However, i referesh the web, then this state has gone.

Ah, i'm using React, and using Cookies with Access and Refresh Token, and wondering "Should i use another state to keep logged in information or not."

Before, i used localStorage and set the state manually, such as "isLogin" : "true" state in localStorage.

However, i'm wondering the way to use accessToken which expires automatically in 30 mins.
Will there ve a neat way to construct this function?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use redux-persist in your application  so that  state is maintained even if you are refreshing page after logged in application.

**Sample redux store configuration:**

```js
import { combineReducers} from 'redux';
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import storage from '@/redux/sync_storage';
import { setupListeners } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/query';
import persistStore from 'redux-persist/lib/persistStore';
import app from '@/redux/slice/appSlice';
const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
  //blacklist: ['app']
}
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
     app,
    
 
})
const initialState = {}
const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer)
const store= configureStore({reducer:persistedReducer,initialState,devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',middleware:[thunk]})
setupListeners(store.dispatch);
export const persistor = persistStore(store, {}, () => {
  persistor.persist();
});
export default store;
```

The below urls will help with the configuration for react application

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@reduxjs/toolkit

https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist

https://kandi.openweaver.com/javascript/rt2zz/redux-persist#Code-Snippets

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to log in again after the relaunch of the browser?

If so, it can be done with Redux store.
Here is the link for documentation.

- https://redux.js.org/api/store

If not, it should be done with session or chrome.storage or something.